# Uniform distribution in Cplex

Tags: distribution, cplex, uniform-distribution

How can Cplex define directly the uniform distribution that the data followed?

Thank you for your all support!

For example:

Case 1: the processing time of plane (parameter) is followd by Uniform Distribution:

process_time[plane] = UD[0.167;0.444]

Case 2: the departure time of plane (parameter) is followed by Uniform Distribution also:

total of service for plane p at airport a served in the o service order = st_pao (auxiliary variable)

depart_time[plane] = enter_time[plane] + min(st_pao)* UD[1.000;1.200]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rand in OPL:

```
int scale=1000000;
range r=1..10;
float UD[i in r]=0.167+rand(scale)/scale*(0.444-0.167);

execute
{
  writeln(UD);
}
```

gives

```
[0.2277 0.23534 0.22615 0.19707 0.28584 0.44196 0.35064 0.39859 0.33126 0.18588]
```